# Relationship between equivalent metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to prove that two metrics $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ defined on a non-empty set $M$, are equivalent if and only if there exist positive constants $\delta>0$ and $\rho<\infty$ such that

$$\inf_{x\neq y} \frac{d_2(x, y)}{d_1(x, y)}\geq\delta \hspace{0.3cm} \text{and}\hspace{0.3cm}\sup_{x\neq y} \frac{d_2(x, y)}{d_1(x, y)}\leq\rho$$

My attempt was to assume that $M$ is bounded (both top and bottom for it to work).

For the implication, we can start from the fact that by definition we have that two metrics are equivalent if there exist $k_{1}$, $k_{2} >0$ such that

$$k_{1}d_{1}(x, y) \leq d_{2}(x, y) \leq k_{2}d_{1}(x, y)$$

From the first inequality as $d_{1}$ is metric we can consider that $d_{1}(x, y) \geq 0$, this is where I wonder if the argument behind this inequality is really a multiplication by an "inverse" in the inequality $k_{1}\leq \frac{d_2(x, y)}{d_1(x, y)}$ Clearly $x\neq y$ for they are metric since this set is bounded, we can assume the existence of an infimum that satisfies the requested inequality for a choice such as $k_{1}=\delta$, is similar for the supremum

but the truth is not clear to me, this supreme really acts on $M$ or on which set is assumed?

Any suggestion to demonstrate this, any help is welcome!

Comment: What is your definition of equivalence of metrics?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Based on "*we can start from the fact that by definition we have that two metrics are equivalent if there exist*", I think the OP means what I called "Lipschitz equivalent" in [this 4 October 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/M_rwL68ibPs/m/10wJvtJcgp4J).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x_0\neq y_0$, one has
$$
\delta \leqslant \inf_{x\neq y} \frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)} \leqslant \frac{d_2(x_0,y_0)}{d_1(x_0,y_0)} \leqslant \sup_{x\neq y}\frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)} \leqslant \rho,
$$
so that multiplying by $d_1(x_0,y_0) > 0$ yields
$$
\delta\, d_1(x_0,y_0) \leqslant d_2(x_0,y_0) \leqslant \rho \,d(x_0,y_0).
$$
This is independent of the choice of $x_0$ and $y_0$, and is trivially true if $x_0=y_0$.
Hence,
$$
\forall x,y,\quad \delta\, d_1(x,y) \leqslant d_2(x,y) \leqslant \rho\, d_1(x,y). \tag{1}
$$
The converse is straightforward: if $(1)$ holds, then it holds for $x\neq y$.
Dividing by $d_1(x,y)$ shows that the map
$
x\neq y \mapsto \frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)}
$
is bounded below by $\delta$ and above by $\rho$.